# Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

So i work in a **Zend Framework** project and i am using **Doctrine**, i create my Form, Controller and Entities, but when i run my project i got this error :

```
Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion
```

**This is my Entity :**

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{   
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="publication", type="boolean")
     */
    private $publication;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \Datetime();
    }
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set publication
     *
     * @param boolean $publication
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setPublication($publication)
    {
        $this->publication = $publication;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get publication
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getPublication()
    {
        return $this->publication;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\Image $image
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setImage(\Application\Entity\Image $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \Application\Entity\Image 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

}
```

**And this is Form with fields validation:**

```
class ArticleForm extends Form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface

{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'title',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Title'
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'hidden',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'content',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type' => 'textera',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Content'
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'date',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'class' => 'datepicker',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Date',
                ),
        ));


        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'publication',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type' => 'Checkbox',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'url',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'id'   => 'files',
                        'class'=> 'upload'  
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Url'
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'alt',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Alt'
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Go',
                'class' => 'submit',
            ),
        ));

        $this->setInputFilter($this->createInputFilter());
    }

    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
    {         
        parent::__construct($name, $options);
    }

    public function createInputFilter()
    {
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory     = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'title',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                            'min'      => 6,
                                            'max'      => 100,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'content',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                            'min'      => 10,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'publication',
                    'required' => false,
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'date',
                    'required' => true,
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'image',
                    'required' => true,
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }

    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get the object manager
     *
     * @return ObjectManager
     */
    public function getObjectManager() {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }

}
```

**Then my Action :**

```
public function addAction()
{       
    $form = new ArticleForm($this->getObjectManager());
    $article = new Article();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($this->getObjectManager(), get_class($article));
    $form->setHydrator($hydrator);
    $form->bind($article);
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
        if ($request->isPost()) 
        {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $this->getObjectManager()->persist($article);
                    $this->getObjectManager()->flush();

                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
            }
             }
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user');
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

**Finally my View where i think i have an error :**

```
 <?php 
   $form = $this->form;
   $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('add', array('action' => 'add')));
   $form->prepare();
 ?>
 <?php  
   echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 ?>
 <ul>
    <li>
        <?php echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));?>
    <li>
    <li>
        <label>Publication:</label>
        <?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('publication'));?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Title:</label>
        <?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('title'));?>
    </li>
         // ....
    <li>
        <?php echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));?></li>
    </ul>
<?php
    echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
```

That it's, this is almost my codes, i tried everything and i didn't found any solution, and i think the error in my view, so please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative

Answer (score 3):

its propably because of the date-object.
try to change the type of the form element to date:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'date',
        'type' => 'Date',
        'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'class' => 'datepicker',
        ),
        'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Date',
        ),
));
```

Comment: when u return the form element is it an instance of \DateTime object?

Comment: @MarcelDjaman if the field in your database is of type Date, then it gets automatically converted into a string in your view and if you save the form, the string from the input gets converted into a Date object.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this error when you set an object as attribute instead of a string:

```
$element->setAttribute('class', $object)
```

where $element can be a Form, Fieldset or Element

Answer (score 3):

In general, `Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion` means that the Escape view helper was expecting, but did not get, either a scalar or an object with a `__toString()` method. It's a fancy way of saying "dude, I can't print this."

The solution is to either do your own rendering (without using the form view helpers), or ensure that the form element value is something you can `echo`.

Comment: exactly. And sadly just like "[..] print _this_", the message is overly  imprecise, it does not tell which part/property of the entity causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have an `init` function. Comment out your `__construct` function and write it like this:

```
public function __construct(ObjectManager $em, $name = null, $options = array())
{
    $this->setObjectManager($em);
    parent::__construct($name, $options);

    //here you add all the form elements
    //(meaning: just put all the content of your init() function here)
    //if that's a construct function, you also need to add:
    //private $inputFilter;
    //at the top of your class, it is not declared in your code
}
```

Here's the construct function you provided:

```
public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
{
    parent::__construct($name, $options);
}
```

The error was thrown, because you wrote:

```
$form = new ArticleForm($this->getObjectManager());
```

So the first parameter you passed to the `__construct` function was an instance of `objectManager`, and when it was processed in `Zend\View\Helper\Escaper\AbstractHelper`, there was something wrong. I can't tell you exactly what's going on there, but if you declare the `__construct` function as I demonstrated, everything works fine.